# How do these new websites load pages almost AJAX-like but update the history?

Tags: html, performance, browser, browser-history

I admit. I haven't done much research on my own (damn me).

There are a few websites (Gizmodo, Hulu) that have rapid reload times and appear to be AJAXian, but update the history. It functions like a full page load, but doesn't have the full page load behavior. For reference: I'm using Chrome, but Safari does it too.

I've looked for pre-render tags and that doesn't seem to do the trick. Is this really just a case of super-fast loading? Does everyone with a lean stack benefit? I don't see it, so perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Is this a browser enhancement? If so, what can I do to take advantage?

I *WILL* figure this out eventually. I was just going to hit of SO first before delving into the dungeons of tcpdump and AJAX reverse-engineering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) from the "HTML5" set of APIs.  The pages are using ajax to pull in only the parts that need to change and pushing changes to the URL using `pushState` - then they listen for `popstate` events and update the page as you use the browser's `back` and `forward` buttons.

See also:

- [`location.hash` is dead - long live HTML5 `pushstate`](http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate)
- [The W3's specs (thanks @TheZ!)](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/history.html#the-history-interface)

Comment: that appears to be it. confirming (and waiting for the accept timer), but this seems to be exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Here are the w3c docs for it: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/history.html#the-history-interface

Comment: this answer does, BTW, exactly mimic this behavior entirely. it's time i embraced html5 :\

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it involves the [HTML5 History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html), probably the [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) function.